# c# Connecting to TFS depend on application name (assembly name)

Tags: c#, tfs, httpwebrequest, user-agent

I'm writing a program which connect to Team Foundation Server. Everything works fine. But if I rename my .exe file like "TfsBugs_фЫвваП.exe" (with more then one CAPITAL russian chars) the app crashes.
It crashes on the connect TFS method with error: System.ArgumentException (The value specified contains invalid control characters. Parameter name: value)

```
 try
 {
    const String TFS_URL = @"https://tfs.bss.nvision-group.com";
    tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(TFS_URL));
    workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
  }
 catch (Exception _exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Program will be terminated \n\n" + _exp.ToString(), "Could not authenticate while connecting to TFS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

In the Message Box output I can see:

System.ArgumentException: The value specified contains invalid control characters. Parameter name: value
   в System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.CheckBadChars(String name, Boolean isHeaderValue)

в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetSpecialHeaders(String HeaderName, String value)

в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_UserAgent(String value)

в Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.PrepareWebRequestImpl(HttpWebRequest request, String sessionId, ICredentials credentials, IdentityDescriptor identityToImpersonate, Int32 timeout, String cultureName)

в Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxy.PrepareWebRequest(HttpWebRequest request)

в Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.CreateWebRequest(Uri uri, String command)

в Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.CreateWebRequest(Uri uri)

I think this is a problem:
**System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_UserAgent(String value)**
But why UserAgent is passed to server? It's don't need for connection.
Any idias?